# Is there a way to configure/enable logging on a bucket whose logs are to be collected in another bucket that resides in different region in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Although I am able to collect server logs of a bucket in another bucket in the same region.
Can we create collect server logs of a bucket in one(us-east-1) Region into a bucket in oregaon?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The log-bucket should be in the same region.

[I guess this is to ensure good performance].

Are you looking for any specific use case: I can suggest some alternatives if this known ?